# how to convert ndarray to image and display it using python

Tags: python, image, multidimensional-array

I have converted set of images to ndarray and stored it, now i have to convert them back to images without saving it to disk. I tried with " toimage() " function, but it is displaying only 1 image.

```
toimage(resizedlist.values()[0]).show()
```

resizedlist.values contains the ndarray of 49 images. Is there any way to display images randomly??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is it you want to do? Convert the ndarray's to images or plot the ndarray's as images? In the latter case `imshow` will do what you want.

Comment: @ ebarr I want to plotting ndarray as image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To plot an ndarray as an image you can use matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

random = np.random.normal(0,1,size=[100,100])
plt.imshow(random,aspect="auto")
plt.show()
```

If your image data is stored RGBA, `imshow` will plot the image with the correct colours etc.

For reference, all this information can be found here:

http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/image_tutorial.html

Comment: Is there any way to display/plot an ndarray as images which is stored in a dictionary. Because, i have stored the images as ndarray in a dictionary, it is storing properly, but when it comes for display the same, it is not displaying anything.